# Merging rows in R data frames by certain columns

Tags: r, text, dataframe

I have a large data frame of web forum comments and their associated metadata. I'd like to merge all the rows where the (a) user name and (b) thread ID are the same (i.e, I want each row to represent a user's total participation in a given thread. I'd want the earliest date; the dates in my data frame are currently in DD-MM-YY format. The formatting and word order of the text don't need to look pretty for the type of analysis I'm doing.

So as an example,

```
old <- rbind(c(1, "hello", "bob", "Sept1"), c(1, "world", "bob", "Sept2"), c(1, "hey there", "mary", "Sept1"), c(2, "to be or", "ted", "Aug1"), c(2, "sample text", "mary", "Aug1"), c(2, "not to be", "ted", "Sept3"))
colnames(old) <- c("thread", "comment", "user", "date")
old

     thread comment       user   date   
[1,] "1"    "hello"       "bob"  "Sept1"
[2,] "1"    "world"       "bob"  "Sept2"
[3,] "1"    "hey there"   "mary" "Sept1"
[4,] "2"    "to be or"    "ted"  "Aug1" 
[5,] "2"    "sample text" "mary" "Aug1" 
[6,] "2"    "not to be"   "ted"  "Sept3"
```

would need to look like:

```
     thread comment              user   date   
[1,] "1"    "hello world"        "bob"  "Sept1"
[2,] "1"    "hey there"          "mary" "Sept1"
[3,] "2"    "to be or not to be" "ted"  "Aug1" 
[4,] "2"    "sample text"        "mary" "Aug1"
```

Thanks!

Comment: You using the dataframe tag, but there are no data frames in your question.

Comment: Oops, "old" in the example was meant to be a data frame and I forgot to convert it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `dplyr`,

```
library(dplyr)

data.frame(old) %>% 
    # parse dates to useful format
    mutate(date = as.Date(paste(substr(date, 1, 3), 
                                gsub('[^0-9]', '', date), 
                                '2016'), 
                          '%b %d %Y')) %>%
    group_by(thread, user) %>% 
    summarise(comment = paste(comment, collapse = ' '), 
              date = min(date))

# Source: local data frame [4 x 4]
# Groups: thread [?]
# 
#   thread   user            comment       date
#   (fctr) (fctr)              (chr)     (date)
# 1      1    bob        hello world 2016-09-01
# 2      1   mary          hey there 2016-09-01
# 3      2   mary        sample text 2016-08-01
# 4      2    ted to be or not to be 2016-08-01
```

Note that you need to make `old` into a data.frame, because it's currently a character vector, which is what you get from `rbind`ing other [partially coerced] character vectors.

Comment: Thanks! Much simpler than I had feared.

Answer (score 3):

Using `data.table`

```
require(data.table)
old <- data.table(old)
print(old[j  = .(comment = paste(comment, collapse = ' '),
             date = min(date)),
          by = .(user, thread)])
```

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, the only base R aggregation function that has the flexibility to perform a heterogeneous two-column aggregation like this is [`by()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/by.html). Unfortunately, since `by()` returns its result as a list, this requires the odious `do.call(rbind,...)` trick, and the whole thing ends up being rather ugly and slow. But, for those committed to avoiding add-on packages, here's how it can be done:

```
df <- data.frame(thread=c(1,1,1,2,2,2),comment=c('hello','world','hey there','to be or','sample text','not to be'),user=c('bob','bob','mary','ted','mary','ted'),date=c('01-09-15','02-09-15','01-09-15','01-08-15','01-08-15','03-09-15'),stringsAsFactors=F); ## define data.frame input
df$date <- as.Date(df$date,'%d-%m-%y'); ## coerce to Date type
df <- df[order(df$date),]; ## ensure sorted by date
keys <- c('thread','user'); ## precompute key columns
res <- do.call(rbind,by(df,df[keys],function(g)
    cbind(g[1L,keys],comment=paste(collapse=' ',g$comment),date=g$date[1L])
));
res;
##   thread user            comment       date
## 1      1  bob        hello world 2015-09-01
## 3      1 mary          hey there 2015-09-01
## 5      2 mary        sample text 2015-08-01
## 4      2  ted to be or not to be 2015-08-01
```